# making directory of javascript src folder

Tags: php

there are so many script tag Sources in HTML file...
for eg:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="js/superfish-1.4.8/js/supersubs.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tweet/jquery.tweet.js" ></script>
```

what am trying to do is.. making as same structure of folder as src file... by doing following codes...

```
<?php
        $srcCode = $_POST['doc'];       
        $url=$_POST['Url'];         
        $url_path=$url; 
        foreach($html->find('script') as $script)
        {
                $scriptPath=$script->src;
                $path="";
                $js = explode("/", $scriptPath);
                for ($i=0;$i<(count($js)-1);$i++) 
                      {
                        $path .= $js[$i] . "/";
                        if(!file_exists('folder/'.$path))
                            {
                                mkdir('folder/'.$path, 0777, true);         //line 15
                            }       
                      }
                $jsName = end($js);
                    file_put_contents('folder/'.$path.$jsName,file_get_contents($url_path.$scriptPath));    //line 19           
        }
?>
```

It giving me Warning as:

```
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: in line 15
Warning: file_get_contents(http://localhost/rock/http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in C:\xampp\htdocs\core.php on line 19
Warning: file_put_contents(../include/http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\core.php on line 19
```

here problem are these warning and another problem is how can i avoid that absolute url not to create folder.....
please please do help me giving ur precious time with answer... :)

Comment: Permission problem ...

Comment: actually am getting folder structure like
one is like
-folder
-->js
--->tweet
---->superfish

and another is
->ajax.google.apis.com

Comment: and i don want to create those ajax.google.apis.com folder to be created..